# How to get the Nth LineString from a MultiLineString in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis

I need a function that gets the Nth LineString from a MultiLineString in PostGIS, somthing like ST_PointN that gets the Nth point from a LineString.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use ST_GeometryN(geometry,int). similar to ST_PointN(geometry,int) the index is 1-based.